# JPA não reflete os dados alterados no BD manualmente

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Tenho uma aplicação JavaFX com Hibernate (JPA).

Nesta aplicação eu atualizo uma TableView com os dados que busco do BD (MySql).

Toda vez que clico para o sistema buscar no BD algum dado, ele executa o seguinte código:

```
public Task<List<Pedido>> getPedido(EntityManager em, String numeroPedido){
        return new Task<List<Pedido>>(){
            @Override
            protected List<Pedido> call() throws Exception {                
                TypedQuery<Pedido> query;
                query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pedido p WHERE p.numPedido = :arg1", Pedido.class);
                query.setParameter("arg1", numeroPedido);
                List<Pedido> lst = query.getResultList();

                return lst;
            }
        };
    }
```

Esta execução trás uma lista de pedidos cujo numero do pedido vai na cláusula `WHERE`. Até ai, tudo bem.

Mantendo a aplicação aberta, eu vou até o BD e altero manualmente os dados.

Feito isso eu executo novamente a consulta que deve trazer os dados que acabei de alterar, mas,  os dados que recebo ainda são os antigos.

Se eu fechar e abrir a aplicação, ai eu recebo as alterações que fiz manualmente no BD.

A impressão que dá, é que existe algum tipo de cache configurado.

Também já tentei colocar a linha abaixo no meu persistence.xml mas não obtive sucesso.

```
<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
```

O que pode estar ocorrendo para que a minha aplicação, mesmo depois de executar a query, não busca os dados do BD que alterei manualmente?

## Complemento da resposta:

Seguindo as orientações do colega Joaquim, criei uma classe de conexão com o BD. Esta classe possui uma fábrica de conexões onde solicito uma conexão toda vez que acesso o BD.

```
public class Conexao {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Conexao");   
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    static 
    {
        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("crp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Erro em Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(crp) => " + e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() throws Exception {
        //responsavel pela persistencia
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close() {
        emf.close();
    }    
}
```

Quando preciso chamar uma função de leitura, eu abro a conexão, efetuo a leitura e fecho a mesma.

```
public Task<List<Pedido>> getPedido(String numeroPedido){
        return new Task<List<Pedido>>(){
            @Override
            protected List<Pedido> call() throws Exception {
                EntityManager em = MainApp.getConexao().getEntityManager();             

                TypedQuery<Pedido> query;
                query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pedido p WHERE p.numPedido = :arg1", Pedido.class);
                query.setParameter("arg1", numeroPedido);
                List<Pedido> lst = query.getResultList();

                em.close();

                return lst;
            }
        };
    }
```

Dessa forma, mesmo que o BD seja alterado por alguma outra aplicação, sempre que chamar a função `getPedido()`, terei os dados atualizados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe a implementação nativa do First Level Cache, veja mais [aqui](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/), uma solução é você utilizar o `.clear()` antes das consultas, no seu caso é realmente necessário essas alteração diretamente na base? Tente evitar esse tipo de abordagem.

```
entityManager.clear();
```

Comment: Lendo sua resposta, achei o que estava errando. Na verdade eu criava um EntityManager para toda a aplicação e utilizava apenas ele. Pelo que entendi, eu devo instanciar uma fábrica de EntityManager e para cada solicitação ao BD, requisitar um EntityManager. Vou editar minha pergunta e colocar lá o código da fábrica EntityManager. Obrigado pela ajuda...